# Only Print Lines that End with Certain Numerical Values

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, grep

I have a CSV file made up of a space delimiter and two columns.

I need to `grep` any lines that end with either **06, 12, 18, or 00** in the first column.

**file.txt**

```
2017121106 22.9
2017121109 19.4
2017121112 17.2
2017121115 9999.0
2017121118 9999.0
2017121121 9999.0
2017121200 9999.0
2017121203 9999.0
2017121206 16.3
2017121209 13.1
2017121212 8.8
2017121215 8.1
2017121218 10.5
2017121221 8.6
```

**Attempted Code:**

```
egrep '(00|06|12|18)$' file.txt
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2017121106 22.9
2017121112 17.2
2017121118 9999.0
2017121200 9999.0
2017121206 16.3
2017121212 8.8
2017121218 10.5
```

I am getting an empty return when running this code in the terminal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the logic regarding **"06, 12, 18, or 00"**? Should that list of values be generated programmatically?

Comment: it looks like every 6 hours, starting at midnight.

Comment: @karakfa - yes, just wanted confirmation. Perhaps timing should be different on weekends?

Comment: `egrep` is not looking for the first field, but the line, and your lines are not ending with the values you're searching for.

Comment: If you replace the dollar with a space, it will work.

Comment: @thanasisp, that would make "Dollar Store" an interesting place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So...  The `grep` command doesn't understand "fields". It only understands patterns.  Since your "first column" is a pattern of numbers followed by a space, you'd match *that* instead of using `$`:

```
$ egrep '^[0-9]+(00|06|12|18) ' file.txt
```

Note the space character at the end of the parenthesized expression. The initial `[0-9]+` is in place so that we can anchor this regex to the beginning of the line, which makes sure we're matching the first "field".

A better solution might be to use `awk`, which *does* understand fields:

```
$ awk '$1~/(00|06|12|18)$/' file.txt
```

Comment: The anchor and `[0-9]+` aren't needed since it matches from the left anyway.

Comment: That would be the case if we were sure that there weren't other data that the OP elected not to include in the sample and that all lines contain only a single space. I'm just being pedantic.

Comment: Surely if you were being pedantic it would be `egrep '^[0-9]{8}(00|06|12|18) [0-9]+\.[0-9]$'`

Comment: There are levels of pedantry. :-)  To be truly pedantic, one would use something other than grep.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '!(substr($1,length($1)-1)%6)' file
```

will give

```
2017121106 22.9
2017121112 17.2
2017121118 9999.0
2017121200 9999.0
2017121206 16.3
2017121212 8.8
2017121218 10.5
```

you're looking the the multiples of 6 in the last two digits, translates into `awk` as *print line when remainder by dividing to 6 is zero*

This solution works due to the domain of the data its 24h representation, so it won't have false positives due to other multiples of 6.

Comment: Here, we're splitting the field itself. If it had less digits `!($1%6)` would have worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using basic grep

```
grep '0[06] \|1[28] ' file

2017121106 22.9
2017121112 17.2
2017121118 9999.0
2017121200 9999.0
2017121206 16.3
2017121212 8.8
2017121218 10.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` code may help you in same.

```
awk '(substr($1,length($1)-1)+0== 06 || substr($1,length($1)-1)+0 == 12 || substr($1,length($1)-1)+0 == 18  || substr($1,length($1)-1)+0 == 00 )'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
(substr($1,length($1)-1)+0== 06 ||\
substr($1,length($1)-1)+0 == 12 ||\
substr($1,length($1)-1)+0 == 18 ||\
substr($1,length($1)-1)+0 == 00 )
'   Input_file
```

Comment: DRY: `awk '{val= substr($1,length($1)-1) + 0} val == 6 || val == 12 || val == 18  || val == 0'  Input_file`